comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’
I'm using a linear search algorithm to find the value being search for.
int linear_search(int *array, size_t size, int value){

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (value == array[i])
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    /* x is not found */
    return -i;
}

its printing the error:
ryan@kibet-pc:~/Desktop/alx-low_level_programming/0x1search_algorithms$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -std=gnu89 0-main.c 0-linear.c -o 0-linear
    0-linear.c: In function ‘linear_search’:
    0-linear.c:15:23: error: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Werror=sign-compare]
            15 |         for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
               |                       ^
    cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

how do i solve this?

The best would be to change i to be a size_t (also the return value should be a size_t). Alternatively you can force a cast.

You may want to return the signed ssize_t instead of the unsigned size_t so that when there's an error you can return -1. This works assuming you won't have an array with more than 2^63 elements (which is almost certainly true).

Also, your code has a(nother) bug; if size is 0 then you return 0 rather than a negative value. Probably you want to return -1 rather than -i.

It depends on what you mean by "solve this".  Do you mean "ignore the warning and don't worry about the potential overflow that this code does not deal with", or do you mean "handle the overflow correctly"?

@PaulHankin: That is not the problem the compiler is identifying. The problem the compiler is identifying is that, in general situations, the usual arithmetic conversions induced by comparing two integer types of different signedness can induce a change in value, and that may produce an unintended result of the comparison. Whether i can overflow is a separate issue, and the compiler has not diagnosed it.

You get the warning/error because you are comparing an unsigned value with a signed value:

int  : signed value
size_t : unsigned value

The warning is present because the rules for an unsigned/signed comparison is to convert the signed value to unsigned, and then compare the two unsigned values. This is different from the mathematical result, because negative values are displayed in two's complement (-1 corresponds to 0xFFFF).
As @wohlstad pointed out, the best thing is to change the data type of i to size_t.
In this case you need to return another value which is unsigned.
size_t linear_search(int *array, size_t size, int value){

    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (value == array[i])
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    /* x is not found */
    return i;
}


This answer does not explain why it is a problem to compare a signed integer type with an unsigned integer type.

Why There Is a Warning
The reason there is a warning for comparing integers of different signedness is the < operation will convert the type of at least one of them, and this can change the value and cause an unexpected result. However, as we will see, this possibility does not occur in this specific code.
How a Problem Can Occur
For illustration, consider a C implementation with 16-bit int and unsigned int, where size_t is unsigned int. In this C implementation, the maximum size_t value is 65,535.
The comparison operators require their operands to be the same type. You can compare an int to an int or an unsigned int to an unsigned int. However, when you compare an int to an unsigned int, the int is converted to unsigned int, and then the comparison is performed. This is part of what the C standard specifies as the usual arithmetic conversions.
Consider comparing the int value −1 to the unsigned int value 3 using the < operator. If we want the mathematical result, −1 is less than 3, so this comparison should evaluate as true. However, when −1 is converted to unsigned int to perform the comparison, the value must change. −1 cannot be represented in unsigned int.
Conversions from signed integer to unsigned integer “wrap” in a cycle around the representable values. For 16-bit unsigned int, there are 65,536 values, and converting −1 to this produces −1 + 65,536 = 65,535. Then the < operator compares 65,535 to 3, and the result is false.
This difference between the result of an ideal mathematical comparison and the result of a computed comparison after conversion is why the compiler was designed to issue this warning.
This Problem Does Not Occur In Your Code
Looking at the code for (i = 0; i < size; i++), we can see that the conversion will never cause a problem in this specific code.
In a common C implementation, size_t is at least as wide as int, and i < size will convert i to size_t. This conversion would change negative values as described above. However, since i starts at zero and is never reduced, i is never negative. It always has a zero or positive value, and these are not changed by this conversion.
In an uncommon C implementation where size_t is narrower than int, i < size will convert size to an int. Because int is wider, it can represent all the values of size_t, so the conversion does not change the value, and the comparison returns the same result as the mathematical comparison.
Thus, in this specific case, the warning can be ignored.
(Note there is a hypothetical possibility that size is so large that the loop will allow i++ to eventually increment i beyond the range of int. In that case, the behavior of the program will not be defined by the C standard. This is a separate problem from the compiler warning.)
Solutions
Since we know it is safe to ignore the compiler warning, we can avoid it by explicitly converting i to an unsigned type:
for (i = 0; (unsigned int) i < size; i++)

Then, since the comparison is comparing two unsigned types, the compiler will not issue this warning. (We could have converted i to size_t, but unsigned int works in both the common and uncommon C implementations mentioned above, whereas size_t could cause a problem in the uncommon implementations.)
Another possibility is to change the type of i to size_t. However, then the return statement becomes a problem, because the negation in return -i; would be performed in the size_t type, and the wrapping would produce a non-negative value, but we want a negative value to indicate a failure. Actually, there is an issue with the return statement as is. A caller could pass an array with zero elements, and of course a search for a target value will then not find the target. As written, the routine will return -i when i is zero, so it returns zero. But this is the same value the routine returns when it finds the target in the initial element of an array (with more than zero elements).
Although a caller could distinguish these two cases because they know the array size they passed, it is a bad design to return the same value to indicate success in one case and failure in another. It would be better to design the routine to return −1 in all failing cases and a non-negative value in all successful cases. We could have:
int linear_search(int *array, size_t size, int value)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (value == array[i])
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    /* x is not found */
    return -1;
}

That is an acceptable implementation of the routine for ordinary purposes.
We could also discuss changing the return type of the routine to size_t, but this introduces additional complications, and trying to cover all hypothetically possible situations would require discussion of technical specifications of size_t, what happens when the array has SIZE_MAX elements, whether int and char are the same size, and more. That would make this answer unwieldy, so they are not covered here.

There are already several answers explaining that int and size_t are not the same kind of source code datatype, and this is what the compiler is warning about. It would be senseless to try to provide yet another version of the explanation.
An alternative solution (avoiding such warnings) is to simply change the approach taken:
int *linear_search( int *pA, size_t size, int value ) {
    int *pEnd = pA + size; // rememember the end of the array
    while( pA < pEnd && *pA != value ) pA++; // search for value
    return pA == pEnd ? NULL : pA; // NULL else ptr to found element
}

This returns a pointer to the array element containing the value (that is already known), or it returns NULL. The caller can use pointer arithmetic if it needs/wants the index of the array element.
Many standard C functions return NULL to indicate unsuccessful completion, so this approach would follow standard conventions.


I find it weird to return size on failure. How does one distinguish
between a valid index and an error when the return value is positive?

You need to change the loop control variable to size_t.
To know if the value was not found you ma use few methods.

sentinel value (in your case it is very unlikely size to be equal to SIZE_MAX .

size_t linear_search(int *array, size_t size, int value){

    size_t result = SIZE_MAX;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (value == array[i])
        {
            result = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}


you can introduce a pointer parameter to return the found index

int linear_search(int *array, size_t size, size_t *found_index, int value){

    int result = -1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (value == array[i])
        {
            found_index = i;
            result = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

Or return size_t and error code via pointer .

This answer does not explain why it is a problem to compare a signed integer type with an unsigned integer type.
